# I have 2 items in comboBox1, How do I put selected combobox into if statement ?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two items from an array in my combobox.

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(boylar[0]);
comboBox1.Items.Add(boylar[1]);
```

I want to put them in an if statement,

```
if (comboBox1.ItemSelected.boylar[0] == true)
{
   //do this..
}
else if (comboBox1.ItemSelected.boylar[1] == true)
{
   //do that..
}
```

How do I select it? I have read all other topics but couldn't do it. thanks.

Comment: you didn't vote which one as the answer ....

Comment: Once you have started to get answers, it's improper to then totally remove most of the content of your question. It removes the context that was there when the answers were posted. I've rolled back your edit to the point it was at when people wrote the answers below. (Editing to add "It works now" is also not a valid edit here, BTW.) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code checks for both ComboBoxes **not** having an item selected (a `SelectedIndex == -1` means no item selected).

Try this instead:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 && comboBox2.SelectedIndex > -1)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Bravo");
   }
}
```

If you want the **first item** selected in both:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 && comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Bravo");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you would create the event handler for the ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged event. See more **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx,)**

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;


            switch((string) comboBox.SelectedItem)
            {
                  case "Option1":
                              //TODO: do something
                              break;
                  case "Option2":
                              //TODO: do something
                              break;
                  default: 
                       //TODO: do something
                       break;
            }

 }
```

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 && comboBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bravo");
            }

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 && comboBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bravo");
            }

Comment: Ok yeah, so if you are handling this in the Button Click event, I would say still switch the `ComboxBox1.SelectedItem` value cast as string and handle the different cases for the different options that you would have available on the ComboBox. You could put the `MessageBox.Show("Bravo");` line in the default case.

Comment: @macstac When you edit the question, I would leave the original question description text at the bottom of the question just so people have context. Right now, the way you have left it, it gives future readers no context. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest SelectedIndex or SelectedItem.

Your code as it currently is compiles, but is not related to your question.  You are handling a button click and then checking whether the SelectedIndex is -1 (that means nothing is selected in .NET).

If you want to set the ComboBox to its first item, this is the code you will use:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Remember that C# is 0-based indexing, so 0 is the first item, 1 is the second item, etc.

Comment: check my question again now pls.